# Try To Print Map as str/list/join without succeess

Tags: python, function, dictionary, join, lambda

```
    def intersection(list_1, list_2):

return map(lambda list0 : list(dict.fromkeys(list0)), [x for x in list_1 if x in list_2 ])
print(intersection([5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7], [1, 5, 9, 5, 6]))
```

In **lambda** the func that deletes duplicate and in **[ ]** the list (from list comprehension) the transfered to the func by map.
When I try to turn it into a list / str / join this error accourced. 
What can I do and why is this happening ?
I added one example run that suppose to print [5,6] but returns error.
Be noticed that the list itself (**[ ]**) reutrns alone: [5, 5, 6, 6] because of the duplicates in the original lists.

Also if I change the code from one line to block og code it works:

```
def intersection(list_1, list_2):
my_list = [x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]
small_func = lambda list0 : list(set(list0))
return small_func(my_list)
```

returns: [5,6]

Thanks !

Comment: Please avoid putting code inside of screenshots. Edit this question to contain the code you're having problems with, and also examples for the variables used, and the expected output.

Comment: @HampusLarsson I changed the qustion and made it as the requirments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need map here. Your idea was right to convert to dictionary and than convert back to list but you have to do that only once.

```
def intersection(list_1, list_2):
        return list(dict.fromkeys([x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]))

print (intersection([5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7], [1, 5, 9, 5, 6]))
```